# UNION Returns NULL When First SELECT Returns Nothing

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have a table: T1 that contains two columns Date and Price

```
T1

---------------------------
DATE           | PRICE    |
---------------------------
2018-07-25     |2.00      |
---------------------------
2018-06-20     |3.00      |
---------------------------
2017-05-10     |3.00      |
---------------------------
```

Here are my requirements:

1. If a user enters a date that is not in the DB I need to return the last price and date in the table T1.
2. If a user enters a date that is superior or inferior to one of the dates in the table T1 -- for example if a user enters '2017-05-09' which is not in the table; I have to return the next date above the given date. In this case'2017-05-10'

I am using UNION in my script but it returns empty when one of the SELECT statements returns empty.

I am using a CTE table:

```
DECLARE @DateEntered DATE

WITH HistoricalCTE (Date, Price, RowNumber) AS (
    SELECT R.Date,
           R.Price,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.Date, R.Price ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM T1 R
    WHERE Date = @DateEntered
    UNION
    SELECT R.Date,
           R.Price,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.Date, R.Price ORDER BY Date DESC)                             
    FROM T1 R
    WHERE Date < @DateEntered
    UNION
    SELECT R.Date,
           R.Price,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.Date, R.Price ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM T1 R
    WHERE Date > @DateEntered
)
```

The issue is when I enter superior to all the dates in the table T1, I get an empty result because the first select is returning empty. Any idea about how I would solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You might be overcomplicating this.  If I read your question correctly, we can just take the smallest value *greater* than the input, or if that doesn't exist, then just take the max of the table.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) rn
    FROM T1
    WHERE Date > @DateEntered
)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte WHERE rn = 1)
         THEN (SELECT Date FROM cte WHERE rn = 1)
         ELSE (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM T1) END AS Date,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte WHERE rn = 1)
         THEN (SELECT Price FROM cte WHERE rn = 1)
         ELSE (SELECT Price FROM T1 WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM T1)) END AS Price;
```

### Demo

All the edge cases seem to be working in the above demo, and you may test any input date against your sample data.

Comment: Thanks, for the quick response. But I am having problems when I try to return both Date and Price in the CASE Statement. The error says "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Comment: @William3N Apologies, I missed your requirement of having the price.  Check my updated answer and demo which seem to be working now.

Comment: thanks for the correction it works now. However, I am using a table value parameter to feed the dates to the SP. I noticed that it only works when I enter a single date. But when I enter multiple dates it only returns one record. Thank a lot. Your help put me on the right path, but if you can add more inputs based on what I said, that'd be great.

Comment: That sounds like a great start to another question.